# Determine QWidget that had last focus before button press

Tags: qt, focus, qdialog

I want to implement the following functionality into my Qt application:

- User opens one or more 'input' widgets (instances of an `InputWidget` class), each containing a `QLineEdit` widget
- User opens a 'helper' dialog
- User selects a value in the 'helper' dialog
- User presses the 'Insert' `QPushButton` in the 'helper' dialog
- The selected value from the 'helper' dialog' is inserted into the `QLineEdit` of that 'input' dialog that had the last focus before the 'Insert' button was pressed

So, basically, what I want is that if the user clicks on 'Insert' in the following screenshot, the string 'Apple' should appear in the focused input dialog. The code example below does kind of work, only that the string is (usually, see below) inserted into the second one.

[image]

Here's is the code example that creates this setup:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout,
                             QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QComboBox)
import sys


# this is the missing bit
def determineWhichWidgetHadLastFocus():
    for widget in QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets():
        if isinstance(widget, InputWidget):
            # do something wonderful to determine whether this widget 
            # is the one that had last focus 
            wonderful = True

        if wonderful: 
            return widget
    return None


class BaseWidget(QWidget):
    """ Base widget type """

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BaseWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(name)
        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        pass


class InputWidget(BaseWidget):
    """ InputWidget contains a QLabel and a QLineEdit widget """

    def setupUi(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Input string:")
        self.edit = QLineEdit()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)


class HelperWidget(BaseWidget):
    """ HelperWidget contains a QLineEdit and a QPushButton widget. Pressing 
    the button inserts the content of the edit widget into the edit widget of 
    the last activated InputWidget """ 

    def setupUi(self):
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"])
        self.button = QPushButton("Insert")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.insertString)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def insertString(self):
        widget = determineWhichWidgetHadLastFocus()
        if widget:
            widget.edit.insert(self.combo.currentText())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    diag1 = InputWidget("Input dialog")
    diag2 = InputWidget("Another input")

    helper = HelperWidget("Helper")

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The missing part is the `determineWhichWidgetHadLastFocus()` function.

This function is supposed to do something wonderful that allows it to determine which 'input' was the last to hold focus. Currently, it traverses the list of top level widgets from `QApplication`, but the order of top level widgets doesn't reflect the activation order (it usually, but not always appears to be the order of creation).

One idea that came to my mind was to install an event filter that keeps track of the `FocusIn` events. That would be easy for the `InputWidget` class in my example, but might not work so well for my real application that has many `QLineEdit`s,  `QTextEdit`s and descended classes all over the place. I'd rather not go that way.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the event filter idea is the way to go after all. What I did was first create an event filter class that emits a signal if the sending object is a `QLineEdit` object:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QEvent, pyqtSignal


class inputFocusFilter(QObject):
    focusIn = pyqtSignal(object)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusIn and isinstance(widget, QLineEdit):
            # emit a `focusIn` signal, with the widget as its argument:
            self.focusIn.emit(widget)
        return super(inputFocusFilter, self).eventFilter(widget, event)
```

This filter is installed for a custom `QApplication` class so that any event that is created passes the filter. The signal `focusIn` is connected to a setter function that remembers the last input widget that received focus:

```py
class MyApplication(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super(MyApplication, self).__init__(*arg, **kwarg)

        self._input_focus_widget = None

        self.event_filter = inputFocusFilter()
        self.event_filter.focusIn.connect(self.setInputFocusWidget)
        self.installEventFilter(self.event_filter)

    def setInputFocusWidget(self, widget):
        self._input_focus_widget = widget

    def inputFocusWidget(self):
        return self._input_focus_widget
```

`MyApplication` is used instead of `QApplication` in the first line of `main()`. Now, the call to `determineWhichWidgetHadLastFocus()` in `HelperWidget.insertString()` can be replaced by `QApplication.instance().inputFocusWidget()`, and everything works as intended.